# Joomla administrator 404 page design not working

Tags: joomla-3.x, administrator, error-pages

We have built a website in Joomla 3.0 but joomla administrator is not redirecting it to default 404 error page. [image: This is the error we got when we enter some wrong URL manually.]. How I can redirect it to defualt joomla error page with design.

Comment: why do you need a 404 error page on admin?

Comment: @FFrewin because we under go security audit so team have asked us to implement that.

Comment: There is nothing related to security by implementing what is discussed here.

Comment: @FFrewin yeah that i know it's just nothing to do with that but still if they stated have to fix it.

Comment: there is nothing special to fix here - you don't need a special 404 for the admin - and by the way what you mean with the default joomla error page design?

Answer (score 1):

You should not worry about admin 404 page. None of the front-end users should have access to that section. But if you really want to check it first of all upload a fresh system files to make sure that none of them are broken. Make sure system is up-to-date. If nothing changes that means that one of the extensions you have installed is breaking default system flow (i.e. doesn't let the system to handle the request). If you want to check default admin error page look at `/templates/isis/error.php` (if you use default admin template).

Comment: It is amazing/shocking/sad that you have posted 60 answers on this site and only 13 have been awarded a green tick!  I don't think this is due to a lack in quality on your part.  This community needs something to spark up the culture and awareness about what is needed for this site to thrive.